Estimating a cointegration vector using OLS
I have been reading Hamilton, and just came across the following concept.

To estimate the cointegrating vector, first set the first component to 1. Then, perform a linear regression to estimate the remaining coefficients. Those coefficients are estimated by regressing each timeseries against the timeseries for which we have set the coefficient to 1.

To put this in more mathematical terms, we have a set of timeseries $y_t^i$. We can create a vector out of these individual timeseries, $\vec{y}_t$.
Assume there exists a vector $\vec{a}$, the cointegrating vector. This vector describes the weights required for each timeseries such that a linear combination of them creates a cointegrated timeseries.
To perform the above procedure, assume $a_0=1$. Then, perform OLS between timeseries $y_t^i$ and $y_t^0$. The gradient produces an estimate of the coefficient $a_i$.
My question is why? Where can I find a proof of this, or more detailed explanation?

I should add - I have tried to find more detail in Hamilton, however I find it a difficult text to read. I have ordered the book by Tsay, but this isn't with me yet. Other recommendations for where I can learn more about this specific subject matter would be greatfully recieved.

Why what? What is your why about, exactly?

@Richard Hardy: My answer assumed he was asking why $a_{0} = 1$. But you're right in that the OP might be asking why about the whole procedure ?

This is just a very basic explanation but maybe it will make things more intuitive. In the Engle-Granger case, ( Johansen's methodology is pretty different but it sounds like Hamilton is talking about EG ), you are really looking for a vector $(\alpha, \beta)$ ( the cointegrating vector ) such that
(1)
$$\alpha y_t - \beta x_t = \epsilon_t$$
But, without loss of generality, we can divide (1) by $\alpha$ to obtain:
$$y_t - \beta^{*} x_t = \epsilon_t^{*}$$
So, that's what Hamilton means when he says set the first component to 1. We instead look for a normalized cointegrating vector (1, $\beta^{*}$).
Note that there is an arbitary-ness above in terms of which series to use the normalized value on ? You can get conflicting results depending on which one you use. This is one of the upsides of using Johansen's approach. There's no arbitary-ness issue with his approach. The downside is that the theory behind the methodology is more complicated.
I hope this helps. Enders may provide a more in-depth discussion of this compared to Hamilton. It's worth checking his text out because it's
more basic compared to Hamilton's.

Excuse the stupid questions - but for clarification, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ here are just scalar numbers? Where does your first equation come from? This looks to me to be related to the ADF test where a linear term is regressed out of the timeseries. If you are familiar with Python, the statsmodels lib allows you to run a ADF test with some options. One of those options being to include a constant, linear or quadratic (or none) term in the regression, the purpose of this is to remove a constant, linear or quadratic trend before calculating the final ADF statistic. Am I making any sense?

Hi: No. It's not related to the ADF test but they are both scalars. The idea of cointegration is to find a linear combination of the two I(1) series that is stationary. So, that equation is just the algebraic version of that linear combination being stationary. ( $\epsilon_t$ is assumed IID normal so stationary ) Then, when you normalize, you get a regression relationship.

I don't know your background but Enders explains things in a more introductory manner so I would take a look at his text.  Also, there are many discussions on the internet and I imagine that a lot of them should be fairly introductory also.

and no question is stupid  from my perspective so don't worry about it. sometimes one needs to have a certain background or be directed to more introductory explanations. no problem.

No - I was being stupid. $x_t$ is just another timeseries like $y_t$. I was expecting to see $y_t^1$ and $y_t^2$ hence why I was confused. Now it makes sense to me

btw - is the Enders text Applied Econometric Time Series ?

ah ok - I've just caught up. So the reason why we can use OLS here is because we are regressing $y_t$ against $x_t$ to find the coefficient (gradient parameter) $\beta$. We fix the constant to be zero. In other words, we perform a regression of the form $y=mx+c$ with $c=0$, and $m=\beta$. We also set $\varepsilon=0$, which is statistically valid since the expectation value of $\varepsilon$ is zero.

To exend this concept: Why does it work for more than 2 timeseries?

Hi: The notion of intercept is subjective. You can put an intercept in and compare the results. Whatever regression allows is allowed here also. As far as the text, yes, that's the text. Note that we're not setting $\epsilon$ to zero. It's a random variable just as in OLS. I hope that everything is clearer now. There may be better explanations than Enders. It's probably best to look around on the net. Note that, after the regression, the residuals need to be tested for stationarity. If the residuals aren't stationary, then cointegration does not exist.

As far as multiple series, Engle Granger doesn't handle that. You need to move on and use Johansen's approach which is far more complicated. There is a whole book on the approach written by Johansen himself.

Thanks, great feedback - what is the title of Johansen's book?

This is the book. I don't know your background but it's not an easy book to read. There may be better articles-papers on the internet that explain it for people who don't want all the gory details. I don't know. I've never used Johansen's framework because I tend to not like to use approaches as black boxes. I prefer to have the understanding and it's not trivial to obtain it. ( plus, I don't deal with cointegration these days ). https://www.amazon.com/s?k=likelihood+based+inference+in+cointegrated&crid=35TV5YKCA568J&sprefix=likelihood+based+inference+in+cointegrated%2Caps%2C95&ref=nb_sb_noss

Thanks, for future readers the full title is Likelihood-Based Inference in Cointegrated Vector Autoregressive Models. I have quite a strong math background and I happen to have done quite a lot of research involving likelihood maximization. I'm sure it will be challenging enough but I can probably get my head around it after a few reads of the relevant sections

user3728501. I think, atleast on the application side,  there's a balance one has to find as far as how much of the theory one wants to understand perfectly and how much to get the general idea about. A good math background will help. Katarina Juselius ( a frequent co-author with Johansen ) also writes nice articles on the Johansen framework. Good luck.
